# Wordpress error while searching themes

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded wordpress to my Windows Website hosted in 1and1.
Everything working fine except searching new themes and plugins.
It shows this error when searching for new theme/plugin

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have
>   problems, please try the support forums.

Comment: updates may be blocked on your host? similar issue to this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oe_B_f-EAM

Comment: How can I enable it

Comment: no clue - that's why I didn't provide an answer :-D maybe contact your host, to see if they have an issue with your instalment?

Comment: :) Thank you. I will try contact them.